# Preciso Atualizar uma Pivot Table em uma Excel Web Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

Eu tenho uma aplicação Sharepoint que usa um elemento gráfico de uma Pivot Table em uma Excel Web Access (Web Part). A questão é que eu não consigo uma forma muito viável de atualizar os dados, tenho tentado as seguintes formas para atualizar:

1- Utilizando o Botão Data, que é uma opção dentro da Web Part do relatório.

2- Utilizando as configurações de conexão dentro do arquivo excel antes de subir o arquivo para o Sharepoint, selecionando as propriedades e marcando a opção "Atualizar dados ao abrir arquivo".

3- Utilizando as mesmas propriedades do exemplo anterior e marcando a opção "Atualizar a cada x minutos".

Tendo em vista todas estas "soluções", eu estou tendo os seguintes problemas para cada uma delas:

1- É a solução mais viável de todas, tendo em vista que mostra para o usuário que o gráfico está atualizando, porém se você mudar de página os dados são perdidos, requerendo uma nova atualização.

Além disso o gráfico sempre volta para os dados iniciais do dia em que foi importado, sendo assim quanto mais tempo passar, pior será para atualizar o gráfico, já que a massa de dados irá aumentar.

2- Nesta solução quando abro o gráfico, ele faz uma pergunta para atualizar as querys e dados recebidos, até ai tudo bem, porém ao aceitar ele começa a atualizar mas não retorna **nenhum** tipo de "resposta" que o mesmo está atualizando. Ele simplesmente surge na tela quando termina de atualizar, cuspindo a informação nova. Ele também tem o mesmo problema ao sair da tela e a manter sempre os dados iniciais do dia em que foi criado o relatório.

3- A solução que não dá certo, porque dentro do excel atualiza, muda os valores, já dentro da Web Part não muda absolutamente nada, é como se não existisse, independente de quanto tempo passe.

Bom eu queria pedir ajuda para deixar este relatório de forma legível e com bom desempenho para os usuários, queria saber se há alguma outra forma de fazer isto ou se tem alguma coisa que fiz de errado nas soluções acima. Tentei as formas corretas? Existe mais alguma possibilidade?